# Agregar fotos en galería de edición en Google Play Newsstand

Tags: android, google-newsstand-producer, rss

Me gustaría agregar varias imágenes en una galería dentro de un articulo en Google Play Newsstand, he tratado de agregar por ejemplo 3 imágenes con la medida permitida, pero no pueden ser desplegadas como galería.

```
<media:content url="[URL IMAGE]"
        type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain">[DESCRIPTION]</media:description>
<media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">[AUTHOR]</media:credit></media:content>
```

Este es un ejemplo de mi elemento artículo:

```
    <item>
    <title><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[http://google/wE-bacdkE]]></link>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[Today we’re introducing a new age-based rating system for apps and games on Google Play. We know that people in different countries have different ideas about what content is appropriate for kids, teens and adults, so today’s announcement will help developers better label their apps for the right audience. Consistent with industry best practices, this change will give developers an easy way to communicate familiar and locally relevant content ratings to their users and help improve app discovery and engagement by letting people choose content that is right for them.]]></content:encoded>
    <author>Grupo Jorgesys</author>
    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/online07/appiphone/imagenes/ipad/960x640/2/974/1973850.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>
    <media:content url="http://flv.grupoJorgesys.com/flash/elnorte/articulo/mp3/online/1/489/488838.mp3" medium="audio"><media:title><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:title><media:description><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/online07/appiphone/imagenes/ipad/960x640/2/974/1973852.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android0]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/online07/appiphone/imagenes/ipad/960x640/2/974/1973856.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android1]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/online07/appiphone/imagenes/ipad/960x640/2/974/1973858.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Android2]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/online07/appiphone/imagenes/ipad/960x640/2/974/1973860.png"
    type="image/png" expression="full" width="538" height="190"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Arquean a cafetería]]></media:description><media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu"><![CDATA[Grupo Jorgesys  / Staff]]></media:credit></media:content>

    </item>
```

Comment: hace mucho que no hago nada en android pero mirando su codigo, veo esto -> type="image/png" y despues esto otro -> url="http://.../../../../../../../2/974/1973860.jpg" y no se si al no corresponderse los tipos por un lado dice image/png pero el fichero que quiere cargar es .jpg no si esto puede ayudar saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel muchas gracias por tu aporte, aunque te comento que en realidad hemos comprobado que no importa el mime type, puede cargar sin problema cualquier tipo de imagen, he editado mi pregunta.

Comment: <media:content url="http://www.jorgesys.com/libre/../../../../../../../1973850.png" type="image/png" medium="image" ...... Quizas si añade -medium="image" igual ayuda. Lo siguiente es extraido de algún lugar -> medio es el tipo de objeto (imagen | audio | video | document | ejecutable). Mientras que este atributo puede a veces parecer redundante si tipo se suministra, se incluye porque simplifica la toma de decisiones en el lado lector, así como elimina las ambigüedades entre el tipo MIME y el tipo de objeto. Es un atributo opcional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bien pues gracias a la ayuda de [@AngelAngel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/24/angel-angel), encontré la respuesta, las imágenes definidas originalmente dentro del archivo .rss tenían una dimensión de ancho `538 pixeles por 190 pixeles de altura`, una medida que no podía ser desplegada en la galería. Ahora he generado imágenes de `800px de ancho por 400 pixeles de alto`, las imágenes por fin son desplegadas correctamente mediante este .rss.

Las características de las imágenes en una edición Google Newsstand son:

> **Imágenes en pantalla dentro del cuerpo del artículo y galería**: Los usuarios quieren ver hermosas y grandes imágenes. El lado más corto de
>   una imagen debe ser **800px**, o mayor para una mejor visualización.**